# Largest prime factor in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16, masm, dosbox

My program is supposed to print the largest prime factor of a given number. Am I going in the right direction? As of right now the program just hangs and does not print anything. Am I missing anything that does not exit the loop that checks for the largest prime factor?

```
.model small ; one data segment, one code segment
.stack 100h ; reserves 256 bytes for the stack
.386 ; for 32 bits
.data ; start definition of variables

; your variables go here

.code ; start code portion of program
main proc ; start of the main procedure
    mov  eax,@data ; load the address of the data segment into eax
    mov  ds,eax ; load the address of the data segment into ds
    ; the two previous instructions initalize the data segment

    ; your code goes here



;prime factor function
mov bx, 116984417 ;starting number
mov cx, 1         ;starting conter
xor dx, dx        ;clear data

mainloop:

mov ax, bx ;bx holds number and ax changes

inc cx ; increment counter
noinc:                 
mov bx, ax           

cmp ax, cx           
xor dx, dx ; clear data

div cx ;check for remainder
cmp dx, 0             
jz noinc           
jmp mainloop       
done:                
ret

;print function
mov bx,10 
xor cx,cx   
a:
xor dx,dx   
div bx
push dx   
inc cx
test ax,ax
jnz a
b:
pop dx   
add dl,"0"   
mov ah,02h
int 21h
loop b

    ; the following two instructions exit cleanly from the program
    mov  eax,4C00h ; 4C in ah means exit with code 0 (al) (similar to return 0; in C++)
    int  21h ; exit
main endp ; end procedure

end main ; end program
```

Comment: You might want to explain what you think you are doing.

Comment: Problems at a glance: 1) the `cmp eax, ecx` is useless as is. 2) the `jz noinc` is useless after a `div` as that does not set the zero flag 3) there is no way to exit your loop and get to the printing or even to `.done`

Comment: Single-step your code in a debugger, and check what's in AX and CX every iteration.  And which branch is taken repeatedly, and think about where at that moment the code should jump instead, then change the code so that happens.

Answer (score 1):

> As of right now the program just hangs

Regardless of anything you wrote in your *mainloop*, it does not have any exit and so it will run forever.

> and does not print anything.

Your print function is unreachable because of the infinite *mainloop* but also because of the `ret` in front of it.

> ```
> mov bx, 116984417 ;starting number
> ```

Probably in response to my answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74751323/my-code-keep-repeating-the-input-prompt-after-an-input) did you revert from using 32-bit registers in this question. You should not have done that because here the number 116,924,417 is too big for any of the 16-bit registers.
Also did you notice the typo? In the code you use 1169**8**4417 and in the accompanying text you use 1169**2**4417.

This is my version of the search for the largest prime factor (first draft). I have tested it in DOSBox and it works fine:

```
116924417 -> 11587
116984417 -> 12497
```

The result fits in the 16-bit AX, so you can keep using the 16-bit print function.

```
; IN (eax) OUT (eax) MOD (ecx,edx,esi,edi)
LargestPrimeFactor:
  cmp  eax, 4              ; Number is its own LargestPrimeFactor
  jb   .done
  mov  ecx, 2
.nextFactor:
  mov  edi, ecx            ; EDI is TempLargestPrimeFactor
  mov  esi, eax
  lea  ecx, [edi - 1]
.nextDivision:
  inc  ecx
  mov  eax, esi
  xor  edx, edx
  div  ecx
  test edx, edx
  jz   .nextFactor
  cmp  ecx, eax
  jbe  .nextDivision
  mov  eax, esi
.done:
  ret
```

This subroutine in context. You could make it a proc of course if you feel to.

```
.code
main proc
  mov  ax, @data           ; Not needed in this program
  mov  ds, ax              ; "
  mov  eax, 116924417
  call LargestPrimeFactor  ; -> EAX

  ...

  mov  ax, 4C00h
  int  21h
; -------------------------
LargestPrimeFactor:
  ...
  ret
main endp
end main
```